# Communicate between 2 processes

Tags: c#

I am trying to communicate between 2 programs but I can’t find out how.

```
Process p = Process.Start(Secondprogram.exe, "number = " + number);
p.WaitForExit();
this.Close();
```

I want to receive the number in my second program and use it there.

Or something like:

```
Process p = Process.Start(Secondprogram.exe);
Parameter number = 1200;
p.WaitForExit();
this.Close();
```

And then in my second program:

```
txtSomething.Text = number;
```

Comment: depends on the program. you could try to read the stream from the Process....

Comment: Do you need to communicate only from the first to the second process or also in the reverse direction?

Comment: Only from the first to the second progress

Comment: Googeling the phrase [c# interprocess communication](https://www.google.de/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20interprocess%20communication) immediately gave me this [result](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: wouldn't a simple command-line argument suffice in this case?

Comment: Is `number` a command line argument or do you want to "send" it to the other process when it is already running?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18437474/inter-process-communication-options

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/528652/what-is-the-simplest-method-of-inter-process-communication-between-2-c-sharp-pro

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21101243/c-sharp-interprocess-communication-on-the-same-box

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1802475/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-do-inter-process-communication-in-c

Comment: duplicate duplicate duplicate duplicate

Comment: Sorry I did not know the correct search description for my question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several options:

- Using WCF will allow you to switch between bindings easily. So if you have two processes on the same machine you can use a *named pipe binding* which is a type of inter-process communication. If you later decide to separate processes onto different machines you can just change configuration to, say, *tcp binding* and everything will continue working
- If you are into REST, there will be client-server frameworks, such as as self-hosted ASP NET Web API or Nancy
- If it is something dead simple, you can just write to a file and read from a file, combined with a global named mutex to synchronise access
- There is also a choice of a memory-mapped file, where one process writes to a file and the other reads from it. It's a bit geeky approach and I have rarely seen this in use.
- Or yet another conventional approach is to use a 3-rd party, such as a database or a message queue system

Answer (score 1):

You can use the output stream of the first program as input stream of the second one. Check ProcessStartInfo : https://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: This is an interesting approach. Could you provide an example? I have exacly this kind of situtaiton where I start another process with ProcessStartInfo. Would it also work if I don't wait for the started process to exti?